# Installing pcl1.4 in ROS , please help

Tags: pcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hii ,

By default the old version of pcl get installed which is 1.1.
Standalone version of pcl1.4 works fine but when I try the unstable version I am getting an error this is what I have done to make pcl1.4 working in ros.

1. download perception_pcl_unstable to my ros_workspace folder.
2. then did rosmake, but I get an error about deserialization.

Can somebody please help me out.

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/27834/installing-pcl1.4-in-ros-,-please-help/) by [faizan](https://answers.ros.org/users/1807/faizan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-02-16

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [faizan](https://answers.ros.org/users/1807/faizan/) on 2012-02-16**:
I have even done this : Download perception_pcl_unstable from SVN and overlay it to your
electric installation by placing it first in your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH.   export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=~/perception_pcl_unstable:/opt/ros/electric/stacks:$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH

**Comment by [faizan](https://answers.ros.org/users/1807/faizan/) on 2012-02-16**:
I have even done this : Download perception_pcl_unstable from SVN and overlay it to your
electric installation by placing it first in your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH.

**Comment by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) on 2012-02-17**:
Can you post the exact error you're getting, and the svn path you're checking out?

**Comment by [faizan](https://answers.ros.org/users/1807/faizan/) on 2012-02-17**:
@ Diaz, I am srry but I posted this question in pcl forum, and they are helping me with it. But to help others, I was getting an error regarding desearialize. Then the authors at pcl.org told me to change my svn_url to point it to new version of pcl. I did that thing by uncommenting it in makefile in pcl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After discussion on `pcl-users@pointclouds.org`, it became clear that @faizan was installing the standalone PCL 1.4 library and not the unstable version of the `perception_pcl` ROS stack.

It remains to be seen exactly what svn URL is needed to answer this question fully.

EDIT:

Another option is installing the ALPHA version of the ROS Fuerte distribution, which includes PCL 1.4.

Beware: Fuerte is still very much a [work in progress](http://ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Migration).

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-02-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) on 2012-02-26**:
Now that PCL 1.5.1 is out and they are shooting for 1.6 by end of March, why can't we setup PCL as an external library like we did with opencv? Then this would question could extend to flann, cminpack, etc

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2012-03-05**:
Setting up PCL as an external library is in progress for fuerte.